# Access denied when pulling private registry image using helm with gitlab runner helm chart and ci job

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, kubernetes-helm

I have a kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 2 workers. All nodes have their IP address. Let's call them like this:

- master-0
- worker-0
- worker-1

The network pod policy and all my nodes communication are setting up correctly, all works perfectly. If I specify this infrastructure, it's just to be more specific about my case.

Using helm I have created a chart which deploy a basic nginx. It's a docker image that I build on my private gitlab registry.

With the gitlab ci, I have created a job which used two functions:

```
# Init helm client on k8s cluster for using helm with gitlab runner
function init_helm() {
  docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
  mkdir -p /etc/deploy
  echo ${kube_config} | base64 -d > ${KUBECONFIG}
  kubectl config use-context ${K8S_CURRENT_CONTEXT}
  helm init --client-only
  helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  helm repo add incubator https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com/
  helm repo update
}

# Deploy latest tagged image on k8s cluster
function deploy_k8s_cluster() {
  echo "Create and apply secret for docker gitlab runner access to gitlab private registry ..."
  kubectl create secret -n "$KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_OVERWRITE" \
    docker-registry gitlab-registry \
    --docker-server="https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/" \
    --docker-username="${CI_DEPLOY_USER:-$CI_REGISTRY_USER}" \
    --docker-password="${CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD:-$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" \
    --docker-email="$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL" \
    -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -n "$KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_OVERWRITE" --force -f -
  echo "Build helm dependancies in $CHART_TEMPLATE"
  cd $CHART_TEMPLATE/
  helm dep build
  export DEPLOYS="$(helm ls | grep $PROJECT_NAME | wc -l)"
  if [[ ${DEPLOYS}  -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Creating the new chart ..."
    helm install --name ${PROJECT_NAME} --namespace=${KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_OVERWRITE} . -f values.yaml
  else
  echo "Updating the chart ..."
    helm upgrade ${PROJECT_NAME} --namespace=${KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_OVERWRITE} . -f values.yaml
  fi
}
```

The first function allow the gitlabrunner to login with docker, init helm and kubectl. The second to deploy on the cluster my image.

All the process works well, e-g my jobs are passed on the gitlab ci, no error occurred except for the deployment of the pod.

**Indeed I have this error**:

```
Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/path/to/repo/project/image:TAG_NUMBER": rpc error: code
= Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/path/to/repo/project/image/manifests/image:TAG_NUMBER: denied: access forbidden
```

To be more specific, I am using [gitlab-runner helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_runner_chart.html#configuration) and this the config of the chart:

```
## GitLab Runner Image
##
## By default it's using gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v{VERSION}
## where {VERSION} is taken from Chart.yaml from appVersion field
##
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner/tags/
##
# image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v11.6.0

## Specify a imagePullPolicy
## 'Always' if imageTag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
##
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

## The GitLab Server URL (with protocol) that want to register the runner against
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#gitlab-runner-register
##
gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.com/

## The Registration Token for adding new Runners to the GitLab Server. This must
## be retrieved from your GitLab Instance.
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/README.html#creating-and-registering-a-runner
##
runnerRegistrationToken: "<token>"

## The Runner Token for adding new Runners to the GitLab Server. This must
## be retrieved from your GitLab Instance. It is token of already registered runner.
## ref: (we don't yet have docs for that, but we want to use existing token)
##
# runnerToken: ""
#
## Unregister all runners before termination
##
## Updating the runner's chart version or configuration will cause the runner container
## to be terminated and created again. This may cause your Gitlab instance to reference
## non-existant runners. Un-registering the runner before termination mitigates this issue.
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#gitlab-runner-unregister
##
unregisterRunners: true

## Set the certsSecretName in order to pass custom certficates for GitLab Runner to use
## Provide resource name for a Kubernetes Secret Object in the same namespace,
## this is used to populate the /etc/gitlab-runner/certs directory
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#supported-options-for-self-signed-certificates
##
# certsSecretName:

## Configure the maximum number of concurrent jobs
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
concurrent: 10

## Defines in seconds how often to check GitLab for a new builds
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
checkInterval: 30

## Configure GitLab Runner's logging level. Available values are: debug, info, warn, error, fatal, panic
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
# logLevel:

## For RBAC support:
rbac:
  create: true

  ## Run the gitlab-bastion container with the ability to deploy/manage containers of jobs
  ## cluster-wide or only within namespace
  clusterWideAccess: true

  ## Use the following Kubernetes Service Account name if RBAC is disabled in this Helm chart (see rbac.create)
  ##
  serviceAccountName: default

## Configure integrated Prometheus metrics exporter
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/monitoring/#configuration-of-the-metrics-http-server
metrics:
  enabled: true

## Configuration for the Pods that that the runner launches for each new job
##
runners:
  ## Default container image to use for builds when none is specified
  ##
  image: ubuntu:16.04

  ## Specify one or more imagePullSecrets
  ##
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
  ##
  imagePullSecrets: ["namespace-1", "namespace-2", "default"]

  ## Specify the image pull policy: never, if-not-present, always. The cluster default will be used if not set.
  ##
  # imagePullPolicy: ""

  ## Specify whether the runner should be locked to a specific project: true, false. Defaults to true.
  ##
  # locked: true

  ## Specify the tags associated with the runner. Comma-separated list of tags.
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags
  ##
  tags: my-tag-1, my-tag-2"

  ## Run all containers with the privileged flag enabled
  ## This will allow the docker:dind image to run if you need to run Docker
  ## commands. Please read the docs before turning this on:
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#using-docker-dind
  ##
  privileged: true

  ## The name of the secret containing runner-token and runner-registration-token
  # secret: gitlab-runner

  ## Namespace to run Kubernetes jobs in (defaults to the same namespace of this release)
  ##
  # namespace:

  # Regular expression to validate the contents of the namespace overwrite environment variable (documented following).
  # When empty, it disables the namespace overwrite feature
  namespace_overwrite_allowed: overrided-namespace-*

  ## Distributed runners caching
  ## ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/autoscale.md#distributed-runners-caching
  ##
  ## If you want to use s3 based distributing caching:
  ## First of all you need to uncomment General settings and S3 settings sections.
  ##
  ## Create a secret 's3access' containing 'accesskey' & 'secretkey'
  ## ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/
  ##
  ## $ kubectl create secret generic s3access \
  ##   --from-literal=accesskey="YourAccessKey" \
  ##   --from-literal=secretkey="YourSecretKey"
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
  ##
  ## If you want to use gcs based distributing caching:
  ## First of all you need to uncomment General settings and GCS settings sections.
  ##
  ## Access using credentials file:
  ## Create a secret 'google-application-credentials' containing your application credentials file.
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-cache-gcs-section
  ## You could configure
  ## $ kubectl create secret generic google-application-credentials \
  ##   --from-file=gcs-applicaton-credentials-file=./path-to-your-google-application-credentials-file.json
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
  ##
  ## Access using access-id and private-key:
  ## Create a secret 'gcsaccess' containing 'gcs-access-id' & 'gcs-private-key'.
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-cache-gcs-section
  ## You could configure
  ## $ kubectl create secret generic gcsaccess \
  ##   --from-literal=gcs-access-id="YourAccessID" \
  ##   --from-literal=gcs-private-key="YourPrivateKey"
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
  cache: {}
    ## General settings
    # cacheType: s3
    # cachePath: "cache"
    # cacheShared: true

    ## S3 settings
    # s3ServerAddress: s3.amazonaws.com
    # s3BucketName:
    # s3BucketLocation:
    # s3CacheInsecure: false
    # secretName: s3access

    ## GCS settings
    # gcsBucketName:
    ## Use this line for access using access-id and private-key
    # secretName: gcsaccess
    ## Use this line for access using google-application-credentials file
    # secretName: google-application-credential

  ## Build Container specific configuration
  ##
  builds:
    # cpuLimit: 200m
    # memoryLimit: 256Mi
    cpuRequests: 100m
    memoryRequests: 128Mi

  ## Service Container specific configuration
  ##
  services:
    # cpuLimit: 200m
    # memoryLimit: 256Mi
    cpuRequests: 100m
    memoryRequests: 128Mi

  ## Helper Container specific configuration
  ##
  helpers:
    # cpuLimit: 200m
    # memoryLimit: 256Mi
    cpuRequests: 100m
    memoryRequests: 128Mi
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-latest

  ## Service Account to be used for runners
  ##
  # serviceAccountName:

  ## If Gitlab is not reachable through $CI_SERVER_URL
  ##
  # cloneUrl:

  ## Specify node labels for CI job pods assignment
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/
  ##
  nodeSelector: {}
    # gitlab: true

## Configure resource requests and limits
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
##
resources:
  # limits:
  #   memory: 256Mi
  #   cpu: 200m
  requests:
    memory: 128Mi
    cpu: 100m

## Affinity for pod assignment
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
##
affinity: {}

## Node labels for pod assignment
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
##
nodeSelector: {}
  # Example: The gitlab runner manager should not run on spot instances so you can assign
  # them to the regular worker nodes only.
  # node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: "true"

## List of node taints to tolerate (requires Kubernetes >= 1.6)
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
##
tolerations: []
  # Example: Regular worker nodes may have a taint, thus you need to tolerate the taint
  # when you assign the gitlab runner manager with nodeSelector or affinity to the nodes.
  # - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/worker"
  #   operator: "Exists"

## Configure environment variables that will be present when the registration command runs
## This provides further control over the registration process and the config.toml file
## ref: `gitlab-runner register --help`
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html
##
envVars:
  - name: RUNNER_EXECUTOR
    value: kubernetes
```

As you can see, I created a **secret** on my ci job, no error occurred here too. In my chart, I declare this same secret (by his name) in `values.yaml` file, which allow `deployment.yaml` to use it.

So I do not understand where I am wrong. Why I get this error ?

Comment: Can't be a network policy it seems to me,  since forbidden is a remote host response.

Comment: Seems that your docker registry could not recognize `docker-username` or `docker-password`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my last comment, I suppose that `TAG_NUMBER` variable is somewhere in your CI Gitlab job. However, you are not able to be authorized with the assigned variables in `--docker-username` and `--docker-password` docker flags. Have you checked the credentials used for the connection to `docker-registry`? Or it might be the option to manage secret within a [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_runner_chart.html#providing-a-custom-certificate-for-accessing-gitlab) Helm Chart template.

Comment: Indeed, I notice that the docker username and password I used is the one used by the gitlab runner. But in fact, when the runner launch the job, Kubernetes have no time to pull the image because the created pod used by the runner is killed before my k8s cluster finish to pull the image. The right solution is to used a personal token instead of used the gitlab ci credential.